# Timeout When Trying to Connect to AWS EC2 Windows 2012 Server with RDP/RDC with Windows 8.1 (VM)

Tags: amazon-ec2, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I have a Windows Server 2012 instance on Amazon EC2.

Although I have been able to connect to the server with RDP (yes I HAVE connected) the connection was temperamental. Meaning, I would be working away when the screen would freeze and stop responding, then after a few minutes, it would give the "Reconnecting attempt 1 of 20..." screen and come right back - at least for a little while.

Other times, it would not connect at all. It would allow me provide my credentials and would display a message about "Estimating connection quality..." and then a few minutes later it would give me a message saying that a "licensing error occurred..."

The thing is, if licensing was an issue, how could I have connected before? And after rebooting my VM, how is it that I could connect again (even if the connection dropped randomly).

I then tried from another computer (a Windows 7 laptop) and could connect, but with the same timeout problem after being in the middle of working on the server.

To further cloud things, I was able to connect with no issues from my Windows 7 VM on my old  Mac. No timeouts, connection is fine etc. The three computers are right next to each other (old 2011 MacBook Pro with Win7 VM, new 2013 MacBook Pro with Win8.1, and Dell Laptop runnning Win7), wirelessly connected to the same router on the same network, with the same external IP.

Even stranger, a simple website I setup on the server has trouble loading. The HTML comes over but images get hung up.

The IT company that setup this virtual server to restrict access to our company IP only. I don't seem to see these issues externally - the loading of the website that is.

Has anyone ever had a problem like this with EC2 or just Windows Server 2012 in general?

Comment: This issue still persists but appears to be related to packet size and MTU. When I restrict my MTU manually to 1453, the problem went away, but just on my machine.
Also, this behavior happens on the Web server itself, when trying to browse a site on it through the public domain assigned. Big files/images fail with no error message. 
What's more, this only happens on secure networks - like ours. It's as if the rules allowing us to RDP also restrict packet size. But browsing on a public network is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing intermittent Remote Desktop connection issues with the licensing error as well.

I have an Amazon EC2 Windows Server 2012. We are all so seeing a slow down of the webserver which appears to be related.